# Como subir um projeto Laravel pro servidor

Tags: php, laravel

Fiz algumas coisas para testar o Laravel, fiz tudo no meu localhost com o Xampp e o Composer, agora preciso subir para a DreamHost e não estou conseguindo, quando tento acessar o projeto na DreamHost recebo um código de erro 500, subi todo o projeto, inclusive a pasta `"vendor"`, para subir pra DreamHost só mudei o arquivo `".env"` mudando os seguintes campos:

```
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Eu alterei os campos acima com os dados da DreamHost.

Podem me ajudar ? Quais outras modificações tenho que fazer ? Lembrando que estou acessando o projeto na url da DreamHost mais a pasta `"public/"`, exemplo: `"http://projetolaravel.com.br/public/"`, e recebendo o erro 500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resolvido!
Era uma coisa simples, tive que mudar a minha versão do PHP no servidor da DreamHost, estava com o PHP 7.0 e mudei pra PHP 7.2!

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, pega tudo que tem dentro da pasta public do laravel, e coloque na pasta public do servidor, que será a public_html ou www ...

O restante vai um nível acima. Configure o banco no .env

Vá até o arquivo index.php da pasta public e procure por esta linha de código.

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

Abaixo dela coloque o seguinte código.

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});
```

Isso vai falar pro laravel qual é a pasta public. Eu já coloco esse código no esqueleto que utilizo em todos os projetos.

At-te;